# Firebase gives sometimes only parts of my saved values and sometimes everything

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift5

I'm trying to code my own messenger. I saved the messages in Firebase database. I'm trying to access the messages with the normal way how I do it every time (database.database().reference().child("users")...., but it gives back only a few messages and only sometimes every message

I already tried it with .childAdded but it doesn't work either

```
func fetchMessages() {
        self.messages.removeAll()
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("chats").child(self.chatuid).child("messages")
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snap) in
            guard let data = snap.value as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }
            //MARK: data = (messageID, AnyObject)
            for (messageID, _) in data {
                ref.child(messageID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snap2) in
                    guard let data2 = snap2.value as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }
                    //MARK: data2 = ("message": String, "sentuid": String)
                    guard let message = data2["message"] as? String else { return }
                    guard let sentuid = data2["sentuid"] as? String else { return }
                    let messageToAppend = Message(sentuid: sentuid, message: message)
                    self.messages.append(messageToAppend)
                    self.messageTableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }

//self.messages = Place where I save my fetched messages
```

Firebase-Structure:

```
{


"users" : {
    "V3bLZu61KYTCG0uCWV8LH1f4rRJ3" : {
      "chats" : {
        "x3GzxwmyLbXrQNNyBF2a82KqrHa2" : {
          "messages" : {
            "20191014165454" : {
              "message" : "Heyho",
              "sentuid" : "V3bLZu61KYTCG0uCWV8LH1f4rRJ3"
            },
            "20191014165647" : {
              "message" : "Blabla",
              "sentuid" : "V3bLZu61KYTCG0uCWV8LH1f4rRJ3"
            },
            "20191014165754" : {
              "message" : "Blabla",
              "sentuid" : "V3bLZu61KYTCG0uCWV8LH1f4rRJ3"
            },
            "20191014165800" : {
              "message" : "Fuchsloch",
              "sentuid" : "V3bLZu61KYTCG0uCWV8LH1f4rRJ3"
            },
            "20191014165805" : {
              "message" : "Jlksaö",
              "sentuid" : "V3bLZu61KYTCG0uCWV8LH1f4rRJ3"
            },
            "20191014165808" : {
              "message" : "Jadfsk",
              "sentuid" : "V3bLZu61KYTCG0uCWV8LH1f4rRJ3"
            },
            "20191014165811" : {
              "message" : "Jskldflsö",
              "sentuid" : "V3bLZu61KYTCG0uCWV8LH1f4rRJ3"
            },
            "20191014170041" : {
              "message" : "JALSF",
              "sentuid" : "V3bLZu61KYTCG0uCWV8LH1f4rRJ3"
            },
            "test" : {
              "messange" : "test",
              "sentUid" : "MatesForSports"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "username" : "Acc2"
    },
    "x3GzxwmyLbXrQNNyBF2a82KqrHa2" : {
      "chats" : {
        "V3bLZu61KYTCG0uCWV8LH1f4rRJ3" : {
          "messages" : {
            "20191014165454" : {
              "message" : "Heyho",
              "sentuid" : "V3bLZu61KYTCG0uCWV8LH1f4rRJ3"
            },
            "20191014165647" : {
              "message" : "Blabla",
              "sentuid" : "V3bLZu61KYTCG0uCWV8LH1f4rRJ3"
            },
            "20191014165754" : {
              "message" : "Blabla",
              "sentuid" : "V3bLZu61KYTCG0uCWV8LH1f4rRJ3"
            },
            "20191014165800" : {
              "message" : "Fuchsloch",
              "sentuid" : "V3bLZu61KYTCG0uCWV8LH1f4rRJ3"
            },
            "20191014165805" : {
              "message" : "Jlksaö",
              "sentuid" : "V3bLZu61KYTCG0uCWV8LH1f4rRJ3"
            },
            "20191014165808" : {
              "message" : "Jadfsk",
              "sentuid" : "V3bLZu61KYTCG0uCWV8LH1f4rRJ3"
            },
            "20191014165811" : {
              "message" : "Jskldflsö",
              "sentuid" : "V3bLZu61KYTCG0uCWV8LH1f4rRJ3"
            },
            "20191014170041" : {
              "message" : "JALSF",
              "sentuid" : "V3bLZu61KYTCG0uCWV8LH1f4rRJ3"
            },
            "test" : {
              "messange" : "test",
              "sentUid" : "MatesForSports"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "username" : "Acc1"
    }
  }
}
```

I expected that the code would give back around 10 messages, but it gives sometimes 5, sometimes 3 or even only 2 messages

My firebase-structure of the messages is .child("messages"), then a unique id, then the actual message and the sender at one layer

Comment: please provide a screenshot of your database structure.

Comment: @ConstantinBeer Please, no screenshots for the RTDB. Please include your Firebase structure as text - that way if we need to use it in an answer (and we will) we can copy and paste it. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Also, `ref' is being re-used and that's not going to work if they are stored in another node, and even if they are stored in that ref they've already been read in via the observe so no need to read them again.

Comment: @Jay Ok I added my structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an an answer followed by a suggestion.

Let's start with replicating your structure using some hard coded values

```
users
   uid_0
      chats
         chat_uid_0
           messages
              unique_id_0
                 msg: "My Message"
                 sent_uid: "uid_1"
              unique_id_1
                 msg: "Hello, World"
                 sent_uid: "uid_3"
              unique_id_2
                 msg: "another message"
                 sent_uid: "uid_2"
```

then the code to read in the messages, iterate over them and print out the msg and sent_uid

```
func readMessages() {
    let usersRef = self.ref.child("users")
    let messagesRef = usersRef.child("uid_0").child("chats").child("chat_uid_0").child("messages")
    messagesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let allMessages = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for msg in allMessages {
            let msgText = msg.childSnapshot(forPath: "msg").value as? String ?? "No Msg"
            let sentUid = msg.childSnapshot(forPath: "sent_uid").value as? String ?? "No sender"
            print(msgText, sentUid)
        }
    })
}
```

and the output is

```
My message uid_1
Hello, World uid_3
another message uid_2
```

That being said - your structure is way to deep and should be denormalized. While it may work, as soon as you want to query for items, of find messages posted by a specific user, it just doesn't work.

I don't know your full use case but this would be a better structure

```
users
   uid_0
      name: "Hank"
   uid_1
      name: "Leroy"

chats
   uid_0
      chat_id_0: true
      chat_id_1: true
   uid_1
      chat_id_5: true

chat_id_0
   unique_id_0
      msg: "My Message"
      sent_uid: "uid_1"
   unique_id_1
      msg: "Hello, World"
      sent_uid: "uid_3"
   unique_id_2
      msg: "another message"
      sent_uid: "uid_2"
```

With this structure, it's all very shallow and easy to get to data - perform queries etc. You can quickly retreive all chats that uid_0 is involved with, get any messages that uid_3 ever posted or add an observer to uid_1's chat so others are notified when a chat has been added. Again, this is just an example and may not fit your case but it's something to consider.

Comment: do you think, that your structure is good for a WhatsApp-copy? I want to do something similar like WhatsApp in my own app as an in app messenger